NetSuite - Set Expected Ship date (Line) with a workflow using todays date plus a custom field with the lead time
I have been trying to set up a workflow to set the Expected ship date at line level, it needs to occur after the user keys the item and allow them to over ride the data that's there if they need (so it should populate only if the field is blank).
The lead time is sourced into a stored custom field at line level. The lead time is different per item, so cannot be hard coded to the formula.
I have a workflow set up after field edit on the Item field.
After much trial and error and checking suite answers for numerous responses, I found this one that helped get me in the right direction (solution 2).
nlapiDateToString(nlapiAddDays(nlapiStringToDate(nlapiGetFieldValue('trandate')), parseInt(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_default_lead_time', line))), 'date')

I feel like am maybe close but stuck at how to proceed. I also tried:
nlapiDateToString(nlapiAddDays(nlapiStringToDate(nlapiGetFieldValue('trandate')), parseInt(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_default_lead_time', line))), 'DD/MM/YYYY') 

The error I am getting is "Invalid date value (must be DD/MM/YYYY)"
I did find another suite answer to indicate that DD/MM/YYYY format in the preferences may not be compatible with this I am really hoping there is another way as we need to avid getting a script for this. Surely it it is possible with a workflow? Customer account preferences are DD/MM/YYYY (we are in Australia so this is the correct format for this country).
If I do not use a custom field for the lead time and instead use a hard coded number (ie 30) then the above works. So it only mucks up when I add the custom field.
The last part of this is that I also need to source "Today"s date when doing this, not trandate, but I wanted to solve lead time part first, but if anyone can help with both that would be awesome.

Is this really related to the  language? If it is, provide a complete [mcve], and also add a tag for the dbms used.

NetSuite uses SQL i tagged it as perhaps i should be using something like TO_DATE but i am just not experienced enough and all efforts at that resulted in nothing too.  What i had posted had simly got me closest to what i was looking for.

Currently i found a solution that is to set up a field on the item record itself that doesn't store value and is {today}+ default lead time and then use the workflow to grab that after field edit.  It works.  So it will solve my immediate issue.
